# Is it possible to add custom fields to the product page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is it possible to add custom html or edit existing information on the main shopify pages such as "product" or the other main tabs?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz3z4.jpg

Comment: for the "down-voters" at least you should explain because you down voted, since, maybe who posted the question never posted a question before, or else (so he can learn from his errors)

I think you down voted because the question is unclear, and shows no effort from the person who posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can creating  [extensions for google chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

Try this samples:

[custom fields](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-fields-for-shopify/alfplfpobekffinigeidgmmfjollghln?hl=en-GB)

[ShopifyFD](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopifyfd-dashboard-tool/lffljkleilfpjlmcdnoaghhcbnemelge?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the liquid templates you need to navigate to `Online Store > Themes` then click `Actions` and select `Edit Code` from a dropdown menu:

[image]

To edit the product page template open `product-template.liquid` from `Sections` directory.

Comment: OP referenced [shopify-app] tag, and your answer is only valid for shop-level modification, and I believe the real question is: how do you enrich the online-store product page as a shopify app?